# How to pass django object id to jquery/ajax upon click of a button?

Tags: ajax, django, jquery-ajaxq

I'm trying to implement a `reddit`-like voting system using `jquery`/`ajax`. How can I pass the object `id` of each individual `Post` with the click of the button?

```
{% for post in posts %}
    <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
    {{ post.upvotes }}<button type="submit">Upvote</button>
    {{ post.downvotes }}<button id="downvote" type="submit">Downvote</button>
{% endfor %}

<script>
    # Somehow need to distinguish between upvote/downvote and include object id
    $(?).click(function () {
        var id = id
        $.ajax({
            url: '/ajax/upvote/',
            data: {
                'id': id
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible to add the `id` as an attribute to each button tag with `data-id`. and to know which type of vote, you may add it as well to a data attribute `data-vote`

```
{% for post in posts %}
    <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
    {{ post.upvotes }}<button data-id="{{post.id}}" data-vote="up" class="vote" type="submit">Upvote</button>
    {{ post.downvotes }}<button data-id="{{post.id}}" data-vote="down"  class="vote" id="downvote" type="submit">Downvote</button>
{% endfor %}
```

And add an event the class `.vote` with js:

```
<script>
# Somehow need to distinguish between upvote/downvote and include object id
$(".vote").click(function () {
    var id = $(this).data("id"),
        vote_type = $(this).data("vote");
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ajax/upvote/',
        data: {
            'id': id,
            'vote_type':vote_type,
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Is there any way I can get this id in views.py

Comment: Sure. based on your request method, you may have it in `request.GET.get("id")`, or `request.POST.get("id")` in case of post request.

Answer (score 0):

If you want two different endpoints, you can use onclick attribute for buttons. If you prefer to send vote type as parameter to same endpoint, you can just call as second parameter on click event.

```
{% for post in posts %}
    <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
    {{ post.upvotes }}<button onclick="upvote({{post.id}});" class="upvote" type="submit">Upvote</button>
    {{ post.downvotes }}<button onclick="downvote({{post.id}});" class="downvote" type="submit">Downvote</button>
{% endfor %}

<script>
    function upvote (post_id) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/ajax/upvote/',
            data: {
                'id': post_id
            }
        });
    }
    function downvote(post_id) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/ajax/downvote/',
            data: {
                'id': post_id
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```